# How to get \lewis or \Lewis (in chemfig) to have custom angles and not just 0-7?

Tags: chemfig, tikz-angles

I'm drawing a molecule (p-anisaldehyde) in which one of the bonds is at a 60 degree angle and the atom at the end is inside `\Lewis{}`. I would like to have the two electron groups on the end atom to be slightly turned counter-clockwise, but right now my only options are to put them at 45 degree angles. Here's the code that I'm using (the crazy amount of packages is because I was experimenting with other things and now I don't know which ones are important at this point...):

```
\documentclass[twoside, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\chemfig{\Lewis{4:6:,O}(-[3]C(<[1]H)(<:[3]H)(-[5]H))-C**6(-C(-H)-C(-H)-C(-(=[:60]\Lewis{0:2:,O})-[:-60]H)-C(-H)-C(-H)-)}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And here's the output (the red circle indicates the lewis structure I'm talking about, it's not done by the code):
[image: p-anisaldehyde]

Basically, my problem is that I can't put any other angle except: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 into `\Lewis{}`.

Sorry if I'm doing something obviously wrong or if I'm kind of vague, it's my first time making a post, so suggestions on posting are also welcome! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chemfig documentation has an example, in French, about making a customized `lewis` macro accepting an arbitrary angle in degrees. I am reproducing it *irresponsibly translated* to English. (I am a native Brazilian Portuguese speaker, so I don't master neither English nor French). This example appeared on page 45 (46th page as there is a cover):

```
\example*{Pairs at arbitrary angles}|\makeatletter
\newcommand\mylewis[3][2ex]{% #1=distance, #2=atom #3=list of angles
\tikzpicture[baseline,anchor=base]%
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=1pt,circle,overlay](atom@@)at(0,0){\phantom{#2}};%
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at(0,0){#2};%
    \def\list@angle{#3,}%
    \loop
        \expandafter\grab@angle\list@angle\@nil
        \pgfextractx\CF@dim{\pgfpointanchor{atom@@}\current@angle}\edef\CF@dimax{\the\CF@dim}%
        \pgfextracty\CF@dim{\pgfpointanchor{atom@@}\current@angle}\edef\CF@dimay{\the\CF@dim}%
        \pgfmathparse{#1*sin(\current@angle)/2}\let\offset@xx\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathparse{#1*cos(\current@angle)/2}\let\offset@yy\pgfmathresult
        \draw[line width=.4pt,overlay]
        (\CF@dimax-\offset@xx,\CF@dimay+\offset@yy)--(\CF@dimax+\offset@xx,\CF@dimay-\offset@yy);%
        \unless\ifx\@empty\list@angle
    \repeat
\endtikzpicture
}
\def\grab@angle#1,#2\@nil{\def\current@angle{#1}\def\list@angle{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Once defined, this macro can be used like this:

```
\mylewis{Cl}{15}\qquad \mylewis[3ex]{Cl}{-60}\qquad \mylewis[1.5ex]{Cl}{60,120,240,300}
```

**In response to comment asking for dots instead of lines**

One attempt to provide both `mylewis` and `myLewis`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mylewis[3][2ex]{% #1=distance, #2=atom #3=list of angles
\tikzpicture[baseline,anchor=base]%
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=1pt,circle,overlay](atom@@)at(0,0){\phantom{#2}};%
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at(0,0){#2};%
\def\list@angle{#3,}%
\loop
    \expandafter\grab@angle\list@angle\@nil
    \pgfextractx\CF@dim{\pgfpointanchor{atom@@}\current@angle}\edef\CF@dimax{\the\CF@dim}%
    \pgfextracty\CF@dim{\pgfpointanchor{atom@@}\current@angle}\edef\CF@dimay{\the\CF@dim}%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*sin(\current@angle)/2}\let\offset@xx\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{#1*cos(\current@angle)/2}\let\offset@yy\pgfmathresult
    \draw[line width=.4pt,overlay]
    (\CF@dimax-\offset@xx,\CF@dimay+\offset@yy)--(\CF@dimax+\offset@xx,\CF@dimay-\offset@yy);%
    \unless\ifx\@empty\list@angle
\repeat
\endtikzpicture
}
\newcommand\myLewis[3][2ex]{% #1=distance, #2=atom #3=list of angles
\tikzpicture[baseline,anchor=base]%
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=1pt,circle,overlay](atom@@)at(0,0){\phantom{#2}};%
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at(0,0){#2};%
\def\list@angle{#3,}%
\loop
    \expandafter\grab@angle\list@angle\@nil
    \pgfextractx\CF@dim{\pgfpointanchor{atom@@}\current@angle}\edef\CF@dimax{\the\CF@dim}%
    \pgfextracty\CF@dim{\pgfpointanchor{atom@@}\current@angle}\edef\CF@dimay{\the\CF@dim}%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*sin(\current@angle)/2}\let\offset@xx\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{#1*cos(\current@angle)/2}\let\offset@yy\pgfmathresult
    \draw[fill,black]
    (\CF@dimax-\offset@xx,\CF@dimay+\offset@yy)circle(0.15ex)%
    (\CF@dimax+\offset@xx,\CF@dimay-\offset@yy)circle(0.15ex);%
    \unless\ifx\@empty\list@angle
\repeat
\endtikzpicture
}
\def\grab@angle#1,#2\@nil{\def\current@angle{#1}\def\list@angle{#2}}
\makeatother
```

This way, you can use `mylewis` as before, but you now have also `myLewis` which appears to be what you really needed.

```
\mylewis{Cl}{15}\qquad \mylewis[3ex]{Cl}{-60}\qquad \mylewis[1.5ex]{Cl}{60,120,240,300}

\myLewis{Cl}{15}\qquad \myLewis[3ex]{Cl}{-60}\qquad \myLewis[1.5ex]{Cl}{60,120,240,300}

\myLewis[.8ex]{Cl}{15}\qquad \myLewis[.8ex]{Cl}{-60}\qquad \myLewis[.8ex]{Cl}{60,120,240,300}
```

Please note that I have not delved into much detail over **chemfig** original `Lewis` implementation, so I have only made `myLewis` based on the provided `mylewis` example. Their difference is simply a change making the end points of the line become the center of little circles.

Comment: Thanks, this is great!!! I would have never thought of looking into the French example!  Although, do you know of any way of making the lines the function produces two dots (like in my example) instead?

Comment: @nbingo I tried to add a new macro `myLewis` in which the end points of the lines become dots. I hope you can tinker with this idea and get what you need.

Comment: I would use `\newcommand\myLewis[3][\CF@lewis@dist]{` so the dots are drawn at the distance specified by `\setlewisdist`.

Comment: @ArchStanton Great suggestion! I will edit the answer accordingly.